# MySQL Prepared Statement table 3th

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I am not able to get data using the join query with 3Th table.

Table p:
 - id
 - name

Table s:
 - id
 - name
 - description

Table ps:
 - p_id
 - s_id

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT p.id, p.name FROM p, ps WHERE p.id = 1 AND ps.p_id = 1 AND ps.s_id = 1");
```

Here's the error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object
Thanks

Comment: What does `mysqli_error()` say the error is?

Comment: Where is the 3rd table in your query? It only uses 2 tables.

Comment: Doubt :- why using the query as prepare when all the values are being passed in the query ?

Comment: I suspect what you're trying to do is something like `SELECT p.id, p.name FROM p, ps WHERE p.id = ps.p_id AND ps.s_id = 1`.

Comment: 1. Always use explicit JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Two question:

(1) Have you tried running your query directly from the MySQL command line? And if so does it give you your desired result?

(2) Could you show more of your code. Perhaps the problem located some where else in your code.

For a start try this explicit JOIN query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name 
FROM p
JOIN ps
ON p.id = ps.p_id
JOIN s
ON ps.s_id = s.id
WHERE s.id = 1;
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE p 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     name varchar(20)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO p
(name)
VALUES
('Bob'),
('Jack'),
('John');

CREATE TABLE s 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key,
     name varchar(30)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO s
(name)
VALUES
('blablabla'),
('Foo'),
('Foobar');


CREATE TABLE ps 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     p_id int,
     s_id int,
     FOREIGN KEY (p_id) REFERENCES p(id),
     FOREIGN KEY (s_id) REFERENCES s(id)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO ps
(p_id,s_id)
VALUES
(1,1),
(1,2),
(2,1),
(2,2),
(3,2);
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0810/1)